# Can I point the source_directory parameter at Azure blob storage?

Tags: python, function, azure, machine-learning

I am using AzureML from an Azure Python Function. In this usecase, I am trying to create an Estimator object in my function using the code below. 
As I am calling from an Azure Function I would like to point the source_directory parameter at Azure Blob Storage and store my train.py file in an Azure Blob - i.e. I don't want to point to my local development environment.

Is this possible? If so how do I construct the parameter syntax?

I have tried uploading the file to a Blob store, attaching the Blob store to my ML Workspace and using the file URL for the parameter but no luck. I Have been investigating file storage in Azure functions but still no breakthrough yet.

```
estimator = Estimator(source_directory='https://MyBlob.blob.core.windows.net/amldata/Scripts',
          script_params=script_params,
          compute_target=ct,
          entry_script='train.py',
          conda_packages=['lightgbm', 'pandas'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to achieve the above, but I did discover that I can access my training file from the directory structure to where I deploy the Azure Function. Not quite as elegant as I hoped, so I'd appreciate any thoughts on IF the above approach IS possible. Thanks, J